# Деплой Spring Boot приложения на сервер WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere

Есть сервер **WebSphere 8.5.5.14**.

Пробую сделать деплой на него **Spring Boot** приложения с одним контроллером.

Приложение не деплоется.

В лог сервера пишет:

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application APP NAME
>   DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, simple-spring-boot-0.0.1.war, of application, simple-spring-boot-0_0_1_war.ear/deployments/simple-spring-boot-0_0_1_war, failed to start

Это же приложение деплоется и работает на **WildFly 17.0**.

**UPD**

Удалось найти причину ошибки запуска приложения.

В папке **ffdc** находится файл **exception.log**, в котором находятся ссылки на файлы логов деплоя.

В одном из файлов лежала ошибка:

> [9/2/19 15:01:15:876 SAMT] FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning 
>     SourceId:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl 
>     ProbeId:679 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@e49d4ab4
>     com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: 
>     com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: 
>     Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: 
>     Error creating bean with name &#39;defaultValidator&#39; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: 
>     Invocation of init method failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/validation/Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider&#40;&#41;
>       Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider&#59; 
>       &#40;loaded from file:/**_/lib/j2ee.jar 
>       by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55af772&#41; 
>       called from class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean &#40;loaded from 
>       file:/**/simple-spring-boot-0_0_1_war.ear/simple-spring-boot-0.0.1.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar by

Переключил загрузку приложения в режим:

> Приложения J2EE > simple-spring-boot-0_0_1_war > Загрузчик классов > Классы загружаются начиная с локального класса

Все равно ошибка, только теперь в лог не выводится.

Поделитесь опытом деплоя Spring Boot приложения на WebSphere или куда копать, чтоб понять что именно не так.

Спасибо.

Comment: Это весь stacktrace?